# How to stop downloading PDF in an iframe automatically and instead view the file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, iframe

I have an iframe on my website that loads a PDF file :

```
<iframe src="file.pdf" frameborder="0" width="800" height="600"></iframe>
```

But it's downloaded automatically , I want to view the file not to download it .

So how could I fix this problem?

Comment: I ended up using `react-read-pdf`. This is specific to my case (React). It's not perfect but so far gave me a solution in order to be able display a file content

Answer (score -1):

**Try using embed**

`<embed src="file_url" height="" width="">`

Answer (score -1):

It's downloaded automatically probably because there's additional header `content-disposition: attachment`. If you want to view the file by default it should be `content-disposition: inline`. But this needs to be configured on server side (or maybe you can somehow force it on client side, not sure tho)

Answer (score -2):

You need to tell your server to send that file as application/pdf ("PDF")

...

Bonus titbits:
 - why do you have a PDF on a website? The web page you're displaying your PDF from already displays things PDF files display
 - why are you loading a PDF in an iframe/etc. if you just want it to be downloaded? Why not just link to it

Comment: Bonus no-that-bits: 1. Needs change from person to person. It'

Comment: @Daniel oh yeah? What need is that? The need to use a PDF "because"? Or some actual need?

Comment: I see that somehow my comment was not fully saved :/. I'll try to remember my words. Imagine you have a list of documents and upon tapping on them you get a preview of its content. So yeah, needs are very subjective to your case and his is valid. Also, he's stating that he actually doesn't want to download it (which is what happens when you change the value dynamically)